# How disable caching request parameters in Node js / express js

Tags: node.js, express, caching, xmlhttprequest

I have used a express get function to view some data. but previous parameters for request are getting stored(caching). So how do I disable caching request parameters for node js + express js. My code is given below

```
let driverSess;
let arrkey = 'arrkey'; let arrobj = {};
app.get('/getDriverSess', function (reqdr, res) {
  var randstr = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);//GENERATE RANDOM SESSION ID
  driv = reqdr.query.driv, vehi = reqdr.query.vehi, imei = reqdr.query.imei;
  var randkey = 'sessid'; var randArr = {};
  var chk_Sess = drvrApp.chkAppDriverSess(driv, vehi, imei);//CHECK DRIVER SESSION
  chk_Sess.then(function (result) {
    driverSess = JSON.stringify(result[0].chkSess);
  });
  console.dir(driverSess);
  if (driverSess.includes('success')) {
    //save sessid
    randArr[randkey] = randstr;
  } else if (driverSess.includes('failure')) {
    randArr[randkey] = driverSess;
  }
  arrobj[arrkey] = [randArr];
  res.send(arrobj);

});
```

Comment: express by default wont cache your request. Can you give more details like sample code or something.

Comment: @IRSHAD Please check my code if I have missed anything

Comment: what is the result you are getting and what the expected result?

Comment: The code is executing with right values but the request parameter values are getting cached, so whenever I am calling the api it is showing the output with previously given parameter values and then I need to refresh the http request to get exact result.

Comment: 'refresh the http?' - confused. You have to refresh (call again) http request for next request, right?

Comment: yes, I am recalling the same request to get the exact result else the api is showing the output for the previous request. Please advice.

Comment: @Pal_IT-Dev  which application/http client are you using to make this request?

Comment: It is http-api so it I am calling from both web & android. Both are getting the same issue as, when I refresh the browser the previous result is showing. Where as on 2nd refresh and onwards I am getting the expected result. The exact result should come on the first time.

Comment: you could try adding code inside the 'then' function so that response would be only sent once the result have been arrived.

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake in the mentioned code above so response was showing me erroneous. It is already been fixed now.